# combining two separate mysql databases tables in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have two separate databases from two different sources but with the same data ttypes and rows, can I return both of it's data's to an array to work with both of them as a one source?

Comment: Federated tables? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: Yes you can. You need a single query with `UNION`. Can't really give you more details, since you're not giving any details either.

Comment: But UNION joins to tables that they are in the same database

Comment: Yu need to mix biziclop's and bfavaretto's comments to get the answer. Use two federated tables and JOIN or UNION between them. Warning: will likely pull in all rows from the tables for the joins, so don't rely on anything heavy. You create a federated table using the "CONNECTION" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2 databases are located on the same server, and the structure of both tables is the same, you may use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM `database1`.`table1`
WHERE `condition1`
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `database2`.`table2`
WHERE `condition2`
```

Replace database1, database2, table1, table2, condition1 and condition2 with your real values.

Comment: @Robbie: I read all of them. If you don't like my answer, be more specific, because I can't guess what you think.

Comment: Union can be used to join tables in separate databases as long as they are in the same server.

Comment: Q asks "two separate databases from two different sources". Union suggested above, but response clarifies "But UNION joins to tables that they are in the same database". I posted the fuller response below. It's a mix of everything!

Comment: This only works if the 2 DBs are located on the same MySQL server. It also assumes that the table schemas are the same.

Comment: @Chris: "with the same data ttypes and rows". So yes, the schemas are the same.

Comment: What's a data ttype? ;) Also, why even bother if the rows are the same?

Comment: @ChrisHenry: I am not the one who wrote the question. Ask the OP.

Answer (score 1):

(Credit to biziclop's and bfavaretto's comments above - but posting as an answer to save others from a half answer.)

Summary: Use a federated table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) and UINION (or JOIN).

Details:

Assume you have a "primary" (local) MySQL table and a secondary "remote" database. In your "primary" MySQL binaries, compile it for "Federated tables" - this allows you to access tables on a remote server as if they were local. Federated tables are not enabled by default.

Then create a table in the primary database with exactly the same structure as the table in the remote database, but add the "CONNECTION" string to the end of the create table instructions. This will set it up as a federated table, and will actually get the data from the remote server.

Then query the primary server, using a UNION between the primary table and the federated table (or JOINS, depending on what you want to to) and this will return one set of results as if it came from the primary server only, even though it gets data from the remote as well.

Note that it's not very efficient, with warnings in the manual about how it conducts multiple queries (e.g. starts with a "SHOW TABLES" before every call, and it may return more rows than desired, create local temporary tables etc).